# O Primefaces não enxerga os métodos de minha classe

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Eis meu problema:

No xhtml abaixo (listaDeOSs.xhtml) quando coloco deste modo, ele não reconhece o método que fiz em meu Bean (o método do bean retorna uma lista). O JSF juntamente com o primefaces é mostrado na tela perfeitamente, só que não retornando os dados (No records found).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Listar" actionListener="#{MBean.retornaOSsPorCliente}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
        <p:dataTable var="sza" value="#{MBean.list}">
            <p:column headerText="Cliente">
                <h:outputText value="#{sza.ZA_CLIENTE}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Funcionário">
                <h:outputText value="#{sza.ZA_CODFUN}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Abaixo a tela apresentada que não mostra os dados:

[image: Tela não mostrando os dados]

Em contrapartida, quando utilizo o jsf com html, o código reconhece o método do meu bean e consequentemente funciona (me retornando os dados). Só que fica feio, diferente do primefaces que é bonito.

[image: Reconhece o método retornaOsPorCliente]

Abaixo o meu bean:

```
package br.com.moriahitg.bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


import br.com.moriahitg.dao.SZA990DAO;
/*import br.com.moriahitg.modelo.SA1990;*/
import br.com.moriahitg.modelo.SZA990;

@ManagedBean (name="MBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MBean implements java.io.Serializable {
/**
* 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
List<SZA990> list = new ArrayList<SZA990>();

public SZA990 sza;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<SZA990> retornaOSsPorCliente () {
SZA990DAO szadao = new SZA990DAO();
list =  szadao.getOSPorCliente("000002");
return list;
}
/*  
public Iterator retornaOSsPorCliente (SA1990 sa1) {
SZA990DAO szadao = new SZA990DAO();
list = szadao.getOSPorCliente(sa1.getA1_COD());
Iterator it = list.iterator();
return it;
}
*/  
public List<SZA990> getList() {
return list;
}

public void setList(List<SZA990> list) {
this.list = list;
}

public SZA990 getSza() {
return sza;
}
public void setSza(SZA990 sza) {
this.sza = sza;
}
}
```

Meu faces-cofig abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>MBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>br.com.moriahitg.bean.MBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

Meu web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>t.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Olá Neemias. Qual versão do JSF e PrimeFaces você esta utilizando?

Comment: Olá Murilo, a versão é 4.0 de acordo com o pom.xml

Comment: Resolvido pessoal! A solução foi colocar ajax="false" no commandbutton e reiniciar tudo para limpar o session. Uma advertência para os iniciantes como eu: Caso esteja usando session, mude para request. Digo isso porque as vezes você roda o código correto, mas a informação anterior (a errada) fica armazenada e é ela que aparece em sua tela. Por isso da a impressão de que o que você está rodando ainda está errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta remover o `<managed-bean>...</managed-bean>` do faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

A anotação @ManagedBean faz o papel de apontar a classe como sendo um bean gerenciavel. Procure tambem remover a propriedade (name="MBean") do @ManagedBean. Por default, na tela o JSF vai apresentar o seu BEAN com o nome da classe minusculo #{mBean.metodo()}.

O primefaces não reconheceu os metodos porque você não adicionou os metodos no faces-config juntamente com o seu Bean. Esse é o motivo de somente usar a anotação @managedBean e não mapear seu Ben no faces-config. Pois com a anotação o ja se resolve essas problemas de mapeamento.

Também, em seu botão `<p:commandButton value="Listar" actionListener="#{MBean.retornaOSsPorCliente}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" update="myDataTable" />`, recomendo que coloque um ID para sua DataTable e mande dar um update nesse id update="myDataTable" no botão.

Comment: Obrigado Murilo! Vou seguir suas recomendações!

Comment: Por nada Neemias. Qualquer coisa é só chamar :-)

Comment: Quer dizer que se eu colocar apenas a anotação @managedBean, ele vai adicionar também os métodos?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Os métodos publicos "public" a tela jsf/xhtml vai conseguir ver, mas métodos privados não será visto pela tela jsf/xhtml.